# Issue with ModifyFeatures using FeatureStore

Tags: geotools

We are trying to modify features using `SimpleFeatureStore` and `Transaction` as shown below:-

```
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Example1");
SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) sfSource;
store.setTransaction( transaction );

Filter flt = ff.within(ff.property("the_geom"),ff.literal(polygon));

SimpleFeatureType featureType = store.getSchema();
try {
   store.modifyFeatures( "0", object, filter );
   transaction.commit();
}
catch( Exception eek){
   transaction.rollback();
}
```

and This results us in an error.

```
ERROR 6: SetFeature() must be used on a feature with a FID.
java.lang.RuntimeException: OGR Error: General Error at 
org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.Layer_SetFeature(Native Method) at 
org.gdal.ogr.Layer.SetFeature(Layer.java:145) at 
org.geotools.data.ogr.jni.JniOGR.LayerSetFeature(JniOGR.java‌​:287) at 
org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRDirectFeatureWriter.write(OGRDirect‌​
FeatureWriter.java:1‌​37) at 
org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessL‌​
ockingManager.java:3‌​37)
```

**This process is done on OGRDataSource.**

After this we are trying to modify values using featureIDs but that results me in same error.

```
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Transaction");
    Maplayer MpLayer = this._MapListLayers.get(cmbLayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    Filter flt = ff.id(ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44177"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44178"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44179"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44180"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44181"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44182"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44183"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44184"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44185"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44186"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44187"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44188"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44189"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44190"));
    try {
        MpLayer._SimpleStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        MpLayer._SimpleStore.modifyFeatures("Equipment", new String("Equipment"), flt);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
    }
```

Please help us to modify OgrDatasource.
We have done both the operations on CSVDataSource it works perfectly.
Issue is only in OGRDataStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shubham and @iant when class OGRDirectFeatureWriter function write going to set feature without FID this error was come, for over come this issue you need to assign FID before set feature.

```
public void write() throws IOException {
       if (live == null)
            throw new IOException("No current feature to write");

       // this will return true only in update mode, otherwise original is null
       boolean changed = !live.equals(original);
       if (!changed && original != null) {
            // nothing to do, just skip
       } else if (original != null) {
            // not equals, we're updating an existing one

            Object ogrFeature = mapper.convertGTFeature(layerDefinition, live);

            //Need To assign FID to ogrFeature -- Start 
            String str = live.getID();
            int idx = Integer.valueOf(live.getID().substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1, str.length()));
            ((Feature) ogrFeature).SetFID(idx);
            //Need To assign FID to ogrFeature -- End 

            ogr.CheckError(ogr.LayerSetFeature(layer, ogrFeature));
       } else {
            Object ogrFeature = mapper.convertGTFeature(layerDefinition, live);

            ogr.CheckError(ogr.LayerCreateFeature(layer, ogrFeature));
            String geotoolsId = mapper.convertOGRFID(featureType, ogrFeature);
            ((FeatureIdImpl) live.getIdentifier()).setID(geotoolsId);
            ogr.FeatureDestroy(ogrFeature);
       }

       // reset state
       live = null;
       original = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have run exactly the same code with other stores then it looks like  a bug. You need to produce a testCase that fails and report it at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/

For the developers to be able to help out you'll need to include a relevant datafile.